# maven deploy-file with links to dependencies

Tags: java, maven, gradle, jitpack

As jitpack.io has been down for almost two days now, I am trying to migrate the jars to different repository.

I took the local jars of the required libraries and deployed them with `mvn deployfile`:

```
     mvn deploy:deploy-file \
              -DgroupId=com.github.dmurph \
              -DartifactId=jgoogleanalyticstracker \
              -Dversion=69f68caf8e \
              -Dpackaging=jar \
              -Dfile=jgoogleanalyticstracker-master-69f68caf8e-1.jar \
              -Durl=https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/{your-project-id}/packages/maven \
              -DrepositoryId=gitlab-maven
```

This is great and I can see the jars being deployed and I can link to them.

However it seems that any dependencies for the original library are ignored and when trying to use this I am getting a lot of `Class not found` exceptions of the related dependencies.

Is there a way to publish the jar with correct links to dependencies?

Comment: You need to specify corresponding pom as well: ‘-DpomFile=…’, otherwise it generates dummy pom w/o dependencies

Comment: @AndreyB.Panfilov is right - you need to provide the pom if you want dependencies included. And if you have a pom, you can omit the `groupId`, `artifactId`, `version` and `packaging` properties, as these can be retrieved from the existing pom. That leaves `-Dfile=... -DpomFile=... -Durl=... -DrepositoryId=...`.